# serial port write c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, serial-port

I'm quite new at programming in `C++` and I need your help.

I want to make a simple `GUI` which will communicate with external device through a `serial port` and sanding char type to a device. And my question is next

1. I don't understand `mySirialPort->Write(array<Char>^, Int32, Int32) --- array<Char>^` what kind of type `variable` I need to write in.

Because I get next error.

```
1>Return_NAN.cpp(19): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [2]' to 'char'
1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
1>Return_NAN.cpp(30): error C2664: 'void System::IO::Ports::SerialPort::Write(cli::array<Type,dimension> ^,int,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=wchar_t,
1>              dimension=1
1>          ]
```

my code:

```
char a = "A";        
SerialPort^ mySerialPort = gcnew SerialPort(a);
//mySerialPort->PortName = a;   
mySerialPort->BaudRate = 1200;
mySerialPort->Parity = Parity::None;
mySerialPort->StopBits = StopBits::One;
mySerialPort->DataBits = 8;
mySerialPort->Handshake = Handshake::None;
mySerialPort->Open();
mySerialPort->Write(t,0,1); // problem
mySerialPort->Close();
```

If I write "A" directly to write function there are no errors while I'm compiling.

Thanks for your help,
KB

Comment: `char a = 'A'; ` with single quote

Comment: The actual serial port functions (`CreateFile` / `SetCommState` / `WriteFile` / `CloseHandle`) are better than the .NET wrappers, and from C++ they're just as easy to call (maybe easier).

Answer (score 1):

System::IO::Ports::SerialPort is a .NET class.  Keep in mind that you are using a language extension called C++/CLI, you'll save yourself a lot of time by reading a basic tutorial.  It is different enough from C++ to have a learning curve, a week will do a lot of good to learn the basic types and knowing when to use the ^ hat.

You already found out that writing a string is easy, SerialPort::Write() has an overload that accepts a string.  It will convert the string to ASCII so you can only write character values between 0 and 127:

```
String^ example1 = "ABC";
mySerialPort->Write(example1);
```

Writing a single byte is easiest done by writing to the BaseStream, no conversion is done:

```
Byte example2 = 'A';   // or 0x41
mySerialPort->BaseStream->WriteByte(example2);
```

If you want to write an array of bytes, like the error message says you do, then you have to create an array object:

```
array<Byte>^ example3 = gcnew array<Byte> { 0x01, 0x02, 0x42 };
mySerialPort->Write(example3, 0, example3->Length);
```

There's no fundamental reason to favor writing an array of bytes over writing the bytes one at a time, serial ports are very slow anyway.

Answer (score 0):

the 1st error is simple: you should write: `char a = 'A';` with a single quote, not `"a"` with double quote.

`array^` is clr reference type, it probably expected to something like: `array<char>^ t = {1,2,3};` [look here:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235236(v=vs.100).aspx)

but you better use `write(string^)` [look here:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2sxhat8(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can convert it from c string like this:

```
const char* str = "Hello, world!";
String^ clistr = gcnew String(str);//allocate cli string and convert the c string
// no need to delete, garbage collector will do it for you.
mySerialPort->Write(clistr);
```